# How to click on button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click a button on a website with Selenium in python, and the button clicking works fine, I can see the button being clicked but the code stops running at that point and when I check the website in my normal browser I can tell that the button hasn't been clicked. More specifically, I'm trying to click a `start` button for an `aternos.org` server, and it clicks fine, but the actual starting of the server doesn't go through for some reason.

My code for the start button clicking:

```
start = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'start')
status = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'statuslabel-label').text
print(status)
if status == 'Offline':
    start.click()
    print('Starting server!')
```

Comment: Side note: it does work sometimes, sometimes not. Also, I don't get any errors, it just tells me that it's been clicked even if it doesn't go through.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, to locate and click any **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *ID*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#start"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='start']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```